# Website works in Chrome but not Safari, Firefox or Opera?

Tags: wordpress, browser, cross-browser

It works beautifully in Chrome but in Safari, Firefox and Opera, the menu is broken, and some styles don't apply.

The theme includes css reset and normalize. I think I have to go and add vendor specific styles but I don't know where to start. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is style.css is not getting loaded. See this request result:

Request URL:http://xxx/wp-content/themes/wright/style.css?ver=4.3.1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

Chrome works because it is caching the missing style, making you think it is working.

Check to see why style.css is not being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this problem, I solved it by creating a custom.css and putting in my css folder, registering and enqueuing custom.css, and clearing (not deleting) style.css.